in google apps script find todays date in column A and add tally in corresponding row in column B
I am trying to set up a few easy tally button to collect daily data
the data collected would look like this



date.
Tally 1
Tally 2




dd/MM/yyyy
Cell 2
Cell 3


dd/MM/yyyy
Cell 5
Cell 6



I want to have a script that would check column A with the dates, find today's date and add a tally mark in the tally column 1, then another button will be set to add a tally in column C... and so on
I can write a add tally
function add1() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var numRange = spreadsheet.getRange('B503').activate();
    var numAdd = numRange.getValue();
    numRange.setValue(numAdd+1);
};

but this I need to set the cell it will tally into manually
